# This.parents of parents of parents

Tags: javascript, this, parent

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it...
I have the follow code:

```
<div id="one">
   <div id="two">
      <div id="three">
         <img class="close" id="close" src="../img/close.png" height="15px" onclick="close(this)"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('#one').css('display','none');
</script>
```

With this, if I click on image this will hide the div "one" (Cause I said the name). But... Can I do with some var? I mean... I don't want say on my javascript code the ID I want to do it automatic like a: $(this).parents().parents()parents()... but I know that it no works xD it's for this that I'm asking for your help :D

Thanks so much.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use a variable,`var id='#one'; $(this).parents(id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just use `.parent()` instead of `.parents()` like so:

```
$('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().css('display','none');
});
```

jQuery Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: Ho Thanks so much :D It was fail cause I used $(this).parents().parents().... with 's'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation, it might be easiest to add a class (for example `.select-this-one`) to the div which you want to select when clicking the image, then do the following:

```
$('.close').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('.select-this-one').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parents use parent:

```
$('.close').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().css('display','none');
});
```

but you still have to count how many levels you want to go up